# Right ideals of a ring $R$ with J(R) nil

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Assume that $R$ is a unital ring with nil Jacobson radical $J(R)$. If each right ideal   of $R/J(R)$ is idempotent, is it necessarily true that each right ideal of $R$  is  idempotent or nil?

If $I$ is a right ideal of $R$ contained in $J(R)$ then the result follows. If $I$ is a right ideal of $R$ containing $J(R)$ and $x\in I$ then $x+ J(R)=∑x_t y_t  +J(R)$ (a finite sum over $t$ with $x_t,y_t\in I$). Hence $x-∑x_t y_t$ is a nilpotent element as it belongs to $J(R)$...

That is all my try! Thanks for any pushing suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field, $S=F\times F$, and $M=F\times\{0\}$ and use the trivial extension $R=S\times M$ where $(s,m)+(s',m')=(s+s',m+m')$ and $(s,m)(s',m')=(ss', sm'+ms')$.

Clearly $J(R)=\{0\}\times M$ is nil (in fact it squares to zero.) Also $R/J(R)\cong F\times F$ has all right ideals idempotent.

Now look at $I:=(\{0\}\times F, M)\lhd R$. It's not nil (since it's not contained in $J(R)$) and it's not idempotent (since $I^2=(\{0\}\times F,\{0\})$.)

Comment: I guess any  right ideal of your $R$ is the sum of a nil and an idempotent. Right?

Comment: @karparvar I'm not totally sure, offhand. Maybe! Are you going to use this example in research?

Comment: With an attribution of course! I would appreciate you (Ryan Schwiebert) in advance!

Comment: Sure, that sounds fine. I hadn't ever heard of such an example, and I was particularly pleased to think of this solution. Hopefully there is not a much simpler example that I'm overlooking...

Comment: I'm very curious to see the end result of your efforts.

Comment: I wonder if my hypotheses ($J(R)$ nil and the right ideals of $R/J(R)$ idempotent) lead also to $R/J(R)$ having DCC on right annihilators. If so, $R/J(R)$ would be a finite direct sum of unital simple rings by the Lanski's article: "Idempotent ideals and Noetherian polynomial rings" that you introduced to me. Should I post it as a  new question?

Comment: @karparvar I'm not sure I understand your new question. Obviously commutative nonnoetherian Von Neumann regular rings have all right ideals idempotent, but fail the DCC on annihilators

Comment: In fact, if $I_1⊊I_2⊊...$ is a strictly ascending chain of ideals then $ann(I_1)⊇ann(I_2)⊇...$ is a decending chain of annihilators. But, why is it strict?

Comment: @karparvar when e is idempotent, $eR$ is an annihilator ideal, and a nonNoetherian VNR ring has both infinite ascending and infinite descending chains of these.